# Is it possible to use one propertyMap for ModelMapper (in spring boot) to map in both directions (DTO to Entity and Entity to DTO)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Good Morning, i used Model Mapper in spring boot to convert my Entity to a DTO ( i configured Model Mapper buy setting the correct property Map) but i couldn't use the same property Map to convert the same DTO to the Entity.

I think that one Property Map can be enough to do the mapping in both directions:
my Map:

```
public class UserPropertyMap extends PropertyMap<UserEntity, UserDTO> {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        map().setId_user(source.getId());
        map().setName(source.getName());
        map().setId_profile(source.getProfile().getId());
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: IF you are not bound to using ModelMapper, [mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/) is a very easy to use mapping framework

Comment: thanks for suggestion, i see that mapStruct got @InheritInverseConfiguration to reverse map

Answer (score 0):

With the current ModelMapper Version 2.4.2 it is **not possible** I'm afraid.

The reason is It's hard to define how ModelMapper should map destination to source if it only know how to map source to destination.

For example, if we had a converter `toUpperCase` using to map `entity.firstName` to `dto.firstName` like this `using(toUpperCase).map(entity.firstName, dto.firstName)`.
How can we reverse-map this?

There is a related [github issue](https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/309). Check that out!